# sklearn RandomForestClassifier active paths or ended nodes

Tags: scikit-learn

Can the active paths or ended nodes within each tree of sklearn RandomForestClassifier be exposed?

What I would like to know is in which node within the decision tree the decision was made. The information must be there there but didn't find a way to access it.

In other works, after I already have a trained RandomForestClassifier and I'm using the predict or similar function, in which node for each of the decision trees the decision was made.

Thanks,

R

Comment: what did you try so far and who does your code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `apply` method (see [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.apply)) of the random forest, to get for each tree in the forest the index of the leaf it ended up in. This is calling the `apply` method of the `tree_` attribute of the decision tree estimator.

You can find out more about the underlying tree object [in the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L2165). The `values` attribute gives you for each node the labels of the training points that ended up into that leaf for example.